# How to open another jframe with button click in different package

Tags: java, swing, jframe, package, buttonclick

i am developing a java application using swing with the help of net beans. i have to open different j frame which is in different java file in another package.. with a button click.

i also want to transfer information from the current page (j frame) to the redirected j frame.
information like content of text field, radio button drop down list etc..

help me with what to write in button click action listener....

```
 /*
  * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
  * and open the template in the editor.
  */
 /*
  * CriptUI.java
  *
  * Created on 31 Aug, 2013, 6:05:02 PM
  */

 package crypt;

 /**
  *
  * @author Nitin
  */
 public class CryptUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/** Creates new form CriptUI */
public CryptUI() {
    initComponents();
}

/** This method is called from within the constructor to
 * initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
 * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jSpinner1 = new javax.swing.JSpinner();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    jPanel4 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenu2 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jMenuItem2 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenuItem3 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenuItem4 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jSeparator1 = new javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator();
    jMenuItem5 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 628, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 28, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    jPanel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));

    jLabel1.setText("Chose Algorithm:");

    jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));

    jLabel2.setText("Number of itterations:");

    jSpinner1.setModel(new javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel(1, 1, 99, 1));

    jButton1.setText("Encrypt Text");

    jLabel3.setText("Generated soft key to decrypt:");

    jLabel4.setText("Enter key:");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jComboBox1, 0, 218, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(jSpinner1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 218, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 98, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addComponent(jSpinner1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(45, 45, 45)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 77, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel3)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    jPanel3.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));

    jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
    jTextArea1.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
    jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
    jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 362, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(35, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 240, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    jPanel4.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));

    jButton2.setText("Send");
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton3.setText("Export");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel4Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel4);
    jPanel4.setLayout(jPanel4Layout);
    jPanel4Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel4Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(236, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jButton3)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jButton2)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    jPanel4Layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, new java.awt.Component[] {jButton2, jButton3});

    jPanel4Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel4Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addComponent(jButton3)))
    );

    jMenu1.setText("File");

    jMenuItem1.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_F4, java.awt.event.InputEvent.ALT_MASK));
    jMenuItem1.setText("Exit");
    jMenu1.add(jMenuItem1);

    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

    jMenu2.setText("Edit");

    jMenuItem2.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_X, java.awt.event.InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    jMenuItem2.setText("Cut");
    jMenu2.add(jMenuItem2);

    jMenuItem3.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_C, java.awt.event.InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    jMenuItem3.setText("Copy");
    jMenu2.add(jMenuItem3);

    jMenuItem4.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_V, java.awt.event.InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    jMenuItem4.setText("Paste");
    jMenu2.add(jMenuItem4);
    jMenu2.add(jSeparator1);

    jMenuItem5.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_DELETE, 0));
    jMenuItem5.setText("Delete");
    jMenu2.add(jMenuItem5);

    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);

    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(jPanel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jPanel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}

/**
* @param args the command line arguments
*/
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new CryptUI().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu2;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem1;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem2;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem3;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem4;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem5;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel4;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator jSeparator1;
private javax.swing.JSpinner jSpinner1;
private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
// End of variables declaration

 }
```

Comment: in current JVM or separate JVM

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with next code in your `actionPerformed()` method:

```
    AnotherFrame f = new AnotherFrame();
    f.setNeededData(/*object*/);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
```

`AnotherFrame` is `JFrame` which you want to create and show.

`setNeededData(/*object*/)` is method of your frame to transfer neededData.

and last 2 lines show it.

Answer (score 0):

On the click of button you can simply create the object of the JFrame which you want to open and it will load the components in it (as you must be calling initComponents() method in the default constructor).
For passing the parameters from one frame to another you can simply create a POJO and set its properties in the current frame and pass this object to the destination frame while creating the object. 
I hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

On button click ActionEvent:

Create the object of class which has the frame creation function and using that object call the newFrame function :

```
    newframe frm = new newframe(this);
    frm.NewFrame();
```

Suppose this function is in package package `org.xyz.frame;`

```
public void NewFrame(){

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame2");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            try 
            {
                for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager
                        .getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                        break;
                       }
                   } 
            } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(ui);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);

}
```